# Webstorm not showing ids and classes in jquery

Tags: jquery, class, intellisense, identifier, webstorm

Webstorm is not showing identifier and classes in the jquery identifier section when i try to write jquery. Please help i am new to programming and need good intellisense to work. It's not showing the ids and classes like in the image.I have the latest version.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/tips-on-jquery-development-in-webstorm/

Heres my code

It's not showing the ids after the # symbol like it should.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    $("#")
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<button id="btn1">Set Text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure jQuery library is enabled here:

[image: library]

Also note that you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, this completion type is explicit:

[image: working on ctrl+space]

Comment: It works for jquery.I have added the library but not for the jquery identifiers like ids and classes.These doesn't show up in the intellisense like in the images in the link ,i have attached.

Comment: [Works for me](http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/4829/20121102061957.png), updated the answer with the most likely cause of the problem (you need to invoke code completion explicitly).

Comment: How can you get this feature WITHOUT control space?